# Сделать выбор в php

Tags: php, строки, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Необходимо сделать, чтобы из строки

*Выбери а или б* php выводил:

*Как по мне лучше "а", но "б" тоже подходит.*

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Вы про условные операторы: `if () {}` ?

Comment: @Эдуард нет. Задача в том, что из произвольной строки надо вытащить слова, которые стоят после "Выбери" до "или" и после "или" до конца предложения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Задача в том, что из произвольной строки надо вытащить слова, которые стоят после "Выбери" до "или" и после "или" до конца предложения*

```
$str = 'Выбери А или Б до конца строки';

preg_match('~Выбери(.+)или(.+)~', $str, $arr);

var_dump( $arr[1], $arr[2] );
```

Результат:

```
' А '
' Б до конца строки'
```